# how to save runtime created table values into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I create one form when i enter number of Rows & Columns then that number of rows & Column table would be generated i want save values entered into that table into database.Please anyone can help me..
My PHP CODE:

```
<?php
   global $Hostname;   
    global $Username;   
    global $Password;           
    global $Database_name;  
function getConnection()    
{
    $Hostname = "localhost";    
    $Username ="root";
    $Password ="";
    $Database_name="labdata";

    $oMysqli = new mysqli($Hostname,$Username,$Password,$Database_name);   
    return($oMysqli);   
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{       
    echo "<table border='1' align='center'>";           
    for($iii = 0;$iii <$_POST['column'];$iii++)         
    {               
        echo "<tr>".$jjj."</tr>";                           
        for($jjj = 0; $jjj <$_POST['rows'];$jjj++)  //loop for display no. of rows.
        {
          echo "<td>" ."<input type=\"text\" name='$iii'>"."</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo"<form name=\"aa\" method=\"post\">";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"save\" value=\"save\">";
    echo "</form>";
}
$TestName = $_POST['testname'];
$Result = $_POST['result'];
$Unit = $_POST['unit'];
$NormalRange = $_POST['NormalRange'];

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO rct(testname,result,unit,NormalRange) VALUES('$TestName','$Result','$Unit','$NormalRange')";
    $oMysqli= getConnection();
    $oMysqli->query($InsertQuery);

    print_r($InsertQuery);exit();

    while($Row = $InsertQuery->fetch_array())
    {
        $TestName = $Row['testname'];
        $Result = $Row['result'];
        $Unit = $Row['unit'];
        $NormalRange = $Row['NormalRange'];
    }   
 }
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rct</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name='abc' method="post">
        <label for='Table'>Define Table</label>
        <label for='rows'>Row</label>
        <input type="text" name="column"></input>
        <label for='column'>Column</label>
        <input type="text" name="rows"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="aaa()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code:

1. The table containing `<input/>`s should be inside `<form name='aa'>`.
2. The inputs that are in the table should be named something like `$iii[]`.

The `[]` tells PHP to create an array of all the rows in `$_POST`, so you can access `$_POST[0][0]` for row 0, col 0, `$_POST[1][2]` for row 2, col 1, etc.

1. You seem to have rows and columns backwards.
2. All your `<input/>` tags are missing the `/`.
3. There's no form with inputs named `testname`, `result`, `unit`, `NormalRange`, so why are you accessing these `$_POST` values?
4. `fetch_array()` can only be used after a `SELECT` query. `INSERT` doesn't return any values.

Probably other things I missed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must correct the input tag

Replace

```
<input type="text" name="column"></input>
```

To

```
<input type="text" name="column" />
```

Second the upper loop must be row loop instead of colum as column sit inside the row

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{       
    echo"<form name=\"aa\" method=\"post\">";
    echo "<table border='1' align='center'>";           
    for($iii = 0;$iii <$_POST['rows'];$iii++)         
    {               
        echo "<tr>";//start Row here                          
        for($jjj = 0; $jjj <$_POST['column'];$jjj++)  //loop for display no. of rows.
        {
          echo "<td>" ."<input type=\"text\" name='".$iii.$jjj."'>"."</td>";//all TDs must be inside the row
        }
        echo "</tr>";//end row here
    }
    echo "</table>";        
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"save\" value=\"save\">";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

And of course table must be inside the form.

Let me know if this helps